# htaccess 2 different RewriteRule not working together

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have 2 different RewriteRule for 2 urls like this,

1. http://localhost/cartz/mycity/
2. http://localhost/cartz/index.php?route=common/home

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)/([^?]*) index.php?city=$1&_route_=$2 [L,QSA]   # Point 1
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]    # Point 2
```

When I comment 1st rule the 2nd URL works but I am trying to figure out a way to have both the URLS working. Can anyone help me?

**Update 1**

The thing I am trying to solve is, in my case By default my page will either have city or it will be empty something like this,

1. http://localhost/cartz/mycity/
2. http://localhost/cartz/

So, my thought process is, first rule will be applicable for the 1st URL and second rule is for 2nd URL.

In opencart `_route_` is process and re-written as `route`

Comment: The pattern `^([^?]*)/([^?]*)` matches on `cartz/index.php` as well. If your first set of URLs always end with a trailing slash, then include that in your pattern (and probably also anchor the pattern at the end, using $), so that it doesn't apply any more for that second URL format.

Comment: @CBroe Not sure whether you meant something like this ``^(([^?]*)/([^?]*))/$`` it throws 404

Comment: That pattern should match `cartz/mycity/` fine. But rewriting configured .htaccess "loops", until there are no matches any more. So first this will rewrite to `index.php?city=cartz/mycity&_route_=cartz`, and then when it goes into the second round, `index.php` matches your _second_ rule pattern, so this will rewrite to `index.php?_route_=index.php&city=cartz/mycity&_route_=cartz` again. (Surprised you are not getting a loop with that, but a 404.)

Comment: Try and add `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` before the current rules, so that no rewriting will happen at all, when the current URL path is already `index.php`

Comment: @CBroe struggling to achieve and I left with this ``RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`` and accessing something like this ``www.example.com?city=mycity&something=one`` instead of ``www.example.com/city/one`` city will be optional

Comment: You need to state what these URLs should be rewritten to. (Please update your question with this information.) The directives you've posted "look" wrong, but without knowing precisely how they should be rewritten this is impossible to answer. Your 2nd URL doesn't "look" like it needs any rewriting? However, you have a `route` URL param in the visible URL and `_route_` in the rewritten URL? Why do you have two rules, what is the 2nd rule for? Do you have any other directives?

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for your comment and I have add some information to the question.